# Webサイトでの個人情報入力の代用となるファイルについて

Tags: html

## 質問内容

Webサイトでの個人情報入力の代用となる、下記のような形式のファイルが存在すると便利だと思います。

```
{
    "address": "東京都新宿区○○町１－２－３",
    "address_kana": "トウキョウトシンジュククマルマルチョウ１－２－３",
    "last_name": "田中",
    "last_name_kana": "タナカ",
    "first_name": "太郎",
    "first_name_kana": "タロウ"
}
```

こういった形式、つまり

・addressというキーの値として住所が記載されている
・address_kanaというキーの値としてカナ表記の住所が記載されている

というような、個人情報を表現するファイルの仕様を定義した規格などは、既に存在しますか。
またはどこかで提案されたことがある（もしくは提案中）でしょうか。

Comment: この質問を見た方へ:こちらの質問はオフトピックとしてクローズされましたが、その理由についてメタで質問されています。もしご意見があればぜひこちらにお寄せください: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2453/8000

Comment: 参考までに、[Generate a Random Name - Fake Name Generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/) というサイトがあって日本人名にも対応しています(住所や電話番号などには未対応の様です)。同様の機能を持つ [RIG - Random Identity Generator](http://rig.sourceforge.net/) というコマンドがありますが、こちらはアングロサクソン系の名前・地名などにのみ対応しています(カタログファイルを入れ替えれば日本人名への対応は難しくはないでしょう)。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。参考にいたします。

Comment: 話が脇道に逸れますが、個人の情報を一括管理するという意味では、個人情報の入力以前の話ですが、[OpenID](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)ないし[シングルサインオン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3)を思い出しました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu シングルサインオンと聞いて、私も一つ連想しました。Googleアカウントなどでサインアップできるサイトです。こうしたサイトが増えれば、個人情報はGoogleなどに集積され、結果として私が言うファイルアップロードという方法は不要になるように思えます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ファイル形式としては [vCard](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) があります。
しかし、Webサイトでのフォーム入力の代替として使われている例は知りません。

---

ユーザーの負担を軽減する方策としては、フォームへの[自動入力](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill)や自動補完がありますね。
これが現状うまくいっていないのは確かだと思います。
しかし、専用ファイルをアップロードするという新仕様が策定される余地があるかというと、私は厳しいと思います。

Comment: vCard、存じませんでした。ありがとうございます。
イメージぴったりです。

フォームへの自動入力の手段として、ブラウザの機能、Dashlaneなどのプラグイン、自作ブックマークレットなどがあります。
私はそのいずれも使用していますが、ファイルをアップロードできたら、どれよりも楽だと思っています。

Comment: そして、入力フォームを作るのはWebサイト側にとっても苦痛です。コストがかかりますし、かけてもUX的に優れたものを作り、デザインを今風に保ち続けることは大変です。
なので、仕様として策定されなくとも、少しずつでも採用されていく道理はありますし、それが広がればデファクトスタンダードにもなりうると思っています。